# Uglify to .js.liquid

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, liquid, grunt-contrib-uglify

So I've used grunt-contrib-uglify in my workflow up to now with no issues, but now I'd like to be able to output my minified code to a '.js.liquid' file (it's for a Shopify project), which I haven't done before.

I figured it'd be straightforward, but when I run the uglify job I get unexpected token errors for any instance of liquid tags in my source js files. Is there an argument that I need to pass to uglify in order to get the task to complete?

Comment: What are the input and output?

Comment: I'm using uglify to concatenate and minify two files: vendor.js and main.js.liquid. Output is to scripts.js.liquid. `Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected token: name (shop). 
Line 32 in src/js/vendor.js,src/js/main.js.liquid`